# How to get the state of a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

this is how I define my thread

```
public class Countdown implements Runnable{

    public Countdown(){
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    //...
}
```

Is it still possible to get the state of a thread if it is started that way? Like

```
 Countdown cd = new Countdown();
 cd.getState();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it still possible to get the state of a thread if it is started that way?

No.  It is not.

If you want to be able to get the state, you have to keep a reference to the Thread; e.g.

```
public class Countdown implements Runnable{
    private final Thread t;

    public Countdown(){
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public Thread.State getState() {
        return t.getState();
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

By the way, there are other reasons why this is not a great pattern:

- If the reference to the `Countdown` object is lost (e.g. because of an exception during construction of the parent object), you will leak a Thread.
- Threads and thread creation consume a lot of resources.  If there are a lot of these `Countdown` objects, or if they have a short lifetime, then you'd be better of using a thread pool.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
public class Countdown implements Runnable{
    private final Thread thread;
    public Countdown(){
        (thread = new Thread(this)).start();
    }

    public Thread.State getState() {
        return thread.getState();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since it's only implementing `Runnable` you'll have to provider a wrapper method to get the state:

```
class Countdown implements Runnable {
    private final Thread thread;

    public Countdown() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public Thread.State getState() {
        return thread.getState();
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you combined two lines into one though, hadn't thought to use that in this case before.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using the run() method and assign the running thread there, no in the c-tor.
Something along the lines.

```
public class Countdown implements Runnable{
volatile Object thread = State.NEW;
public void run(){
  this.thread = Thread.currentThread();
  try{
///....
  }finally{
    this.thread = State.TERMINATED;
  }

}

State getState(){
  Object t=this.thread;
  return t instanceof State?((State)t):((Thread)t).getState();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say, but you should never start a thread from the constructor. That constuctor is begging for problems. Change so that the instantiator of Countdown is creating the thread.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily always bad to start a thread in the constructor. You do have to be careful about it though, make sure to start it at the end of the constructor. For reference as to why it can be a bad practice see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html

Comment: There are also other reasons to why you shouldn't create a thread in a constructor, and especially with the code that the OP has posted. The class is implementing, and thus exposing itself as a Runnable. That indicates to other developers that they should start/create the thread. He could also get into trouble if someone is subclassing the posted code.